# Weighted covariance with different reliability weights?

Tags: covariance, weights, weighted-data

Suppose observables $X$ and $Y$ possess different reliability weights $w_{x,i}$ and $w_{y,i}$ for the possible elements $x_i\in X$ and $y_i\in Y$ respectively. Considering a sequence of consecutive simultaneous measurements of $X$ and $Y$, how is the weighted covariance $s_{XY}$ calculated in this case?